# Placing react hooks in proper order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with a component that displays a list of blogs. Then for each blog, I map over each category in an array and display that. The code so far is:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "frontity";
import { GridWrap, GridRow, GridColumn } from "emotion-flex-grid";
import Link from "@frontity/components/link";
import CardContainer from "./index.style";

const Card = ({ state, post, libraries, categoryName }) => {
  console.log("post", post);

  const [categoryNameFromId, setCategoryNameFromId] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/categories/${cat}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCategoryNameFromId(data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <GridColumn width={[12, 12, 6, 4, 4]} p={["none", "none", "s", "m"]} py={["s", "s", "s", "m"]} style={{display: `flex`, alignSelf: `stretch`}}>
      <CardContainer>
        <div className="info">
          {post.acf.featured_media ? <img src={post.acf.featured_media.url} /> : <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510337550647-e84f83e341ca?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3289&q=80" />}
          <Link link={`blog/${post.slug}`} className="title">
            {post.title.rendered}
          </Link>
          <GridRow className="date-time">
            <p className="date">{post.formatted_date}</p>
            <p className="reading-time">reading time</p>
          </GridRow>
          <div className="excerpt"><libraries.html2react.Component html={post.excerpt.rendered} /></div>
        </div>

        <div className="share">
          <GridRow justify="between">
            <p>
            {post.categories.map((cat) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <span>{categoryNameFromId && categoryNameFromId.name}, </span>
                </>
              )
            })}
            </p>
            <div className="social-icons">
              <i className="icon kap-facebook" />
              <i className="icon kap-twitter" />
              <i className="icon kap-linkedin" />
              <i className="icon kap-mail" />
            </div>
          </GridRow>
        </div>
      </CardContainer>
    </GridColumn>
  )
}

export default connect(Card);
```

The issue I am having though, is that I get an error in the console saying that "Uncaught ReferenceError: cat is not defined". So I tried moving the hook to a different spot, like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "frontity";
import { GridWrap, GridRow, GridColumn } from "emotion-flex-grid";
import Link from "@frontity/components/link";
import CardContainer from "./index.style";

const Card = ({ state, post, libraries, categoryName }) => {
  console.log("post", post);

  return (
    <GridColumn width={[12, 12, 6, 4, 4]} p={["none", "none", "s", "m"]} py={["s", "s", "s", "m"]} style={{display: `flex`, alignSelf: `stretch`}}>
      <CardContainer>
        <div className="info">
          {post.acf.featured_media ? <img src={post.acf.featured_media.url} /> : <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510337550647-e84f83e341ca?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3289&q=80" />}
          <Link link={`blog/${post.slug}`} className="title">
            {post.title.rendered}
          </Link>
          <GridRow className="date-time">
            <p className="date">{post.formatted_date}</p>
            <p className="reading-time">reading time</p>
          </GridRow>
          <div className="excerpt"><libraries.html2react.Component html={post.excerpt.rendered} /></div>
        </div>

        <div className="share">
          <GridRow justify="between">
            <p>
            {post.categories.map((cat) => {

                const [categoryNameFromId, setCategoryNameFromId] = useState();
                useEffect(() => {
                  fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/categories/${cat}`)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                      setCategoryNameFromId(data);
                    });
                }, []);

              return (
                <>
                  <span>{categoryNameFromId && categoryNameFromId.name}, </span>
                </>
              )
            })}
            </p>
            <div className="social-icons">
              <i className="icon kap-facebook" />
              <i className="icon kap-twitter" />
              <i className="icon kap-linkedin" />
              <i className="icon kap-mail" />
            </div>
          </GridRow>
        </div>
      </CardContainer>
    </GridColumn>
  )
}

export default connect(Card);
```

And the error did go away. But I am pretty sure this is not the correct way to do this. Isn't there a way to have the hook be at the top of the component? Any input would be great!

Comment: Don't use useEffect hook inside jsx template.

Comment: @lissettdm i know that. that's why I asked the question. It would be more helpful if you had a potential solution to the question.

Comment: Remember a `useEffect` happens after your first render, as such `categoryNameFromId` is going to be undefined.  What you can do here for `async` stuff like this is just return a null, or if your async action can take a while, return loading or something like that.. eg before your JSX do ..`if (!categoryNameFromId) return null`, or loading etc..

Answer (score 0):

The calls to API are used to be in the `useEffect` when the component has been mounted, in this case you can move the `useEffect` outside of your JSX and call from there the API.

```
     useEffect(() => {
         const promises = post.categories.map(cat => {
               fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/categories/${cat}`)
                .then((response) => response.json());
         });

         Promise.all(promises).then(data => data.map(item => setCategoryNameFromId(item);))
              
     }, []);
```

Comment: ok, thanks. and then how would i display this though?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the result of the all api calls. For every post.categories item fetch the data and save it, once you have done, update the categories state:

```
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (cat) => {
       const categoryIdData = await fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/categories/${cat}`).then(res => res.json())
       return categoryIdData;
    }
    
   const updateData = async () => {
      let categories = [];
      post.categories.map(async (cat) => {
         const catData = await fetchData(cat);
         categories.push(catData);
      });
      setCategories(categories); 
   }

   updateData();
  }, []);
```

then in the template:

```
 <p>
   {categories.map((cat) => (<>
        <span>{cat.name}, </span>
       </>)
   }
 </p>
```

Of course, you can simplify this using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
       const updateData = async () => {
       const categoriesFetch = post.categories.map(cat => fetch(`${state.source.api}wp/v2/categories/${cat}`).then(res => res.json()));
       const categories = await Promise.all(categoriesFetch);
       setCategories(categories); 
    }
    
    updateData();
   }, []);
```